# Sort a list with all three elements of a list, Erlang

Tags: sorting, erlang

I have a list in random order with structure:

```
L = [[{type1, Str12},{type2, Str22}, {code, Number12}, X],
    [{type1, Str14},{type2, Str24}, {code, Number14}, X],
    [{type1, Str15},{type2, Str25}, {code, Number15}, X],
    [{type1, Str13},{type2, Str23}, {code, Number13}, X],
    [{type1, Str11},{type2, Str21}, {code, Number11}, X],
     ...]
```

Where, StrX, NumberX are variables:
I have to sort it, order by first position string, second position string and third numeric string respectively. And nothing to do with all other remaining elements of the List.
eg. Let us say,

```
L1 = [{type1, "Hello"},{type2, "World"}, {code, "00009"}, "india", 24, ...],
L2 = [{type1, "Alarm"},{type2, "Started"}, {code, "00203"}, "Japan", -, ...],
...etc.
```

Basically L should be like this:

```
L = [[{type1, Str11},{type2, Str21}, {code, Number11}, X],
    [{type1, Str12},{type2, Str22}, {code, Number12}, X],
    [{type1, Str13},{type2, Str23}, {code, Number13}, X],
    [{type1, Str14},{type2, Str24}, {code, Number14}, X],
    [{type1, Str15},{type2, Str25}, {code, Number15}, X], ...].
```

Quite Complicated for me, However, I tried like this but didn't work.

```
SortedHeirList = lists:sort(fun(A, B) -> 
                    get_type1_val(A) =< get_type1_val(B),
                    get_type2_val(A) =< get_type2_val(B),
                    get_Code(A) =< get_code(B),
               end, L).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just `lists:sort/1` didn't work?

```
1> L1 = [{type1, "Hello"},{type2, "World"}, {code, "00009"}, "india", 24], L2 = [{type1, "Alarm"},{type2, "Started"}, {code, "00203"}, "Japan"].        
[{type1,"Alarm"},{type2,"Started"},{code,"00203"},"Japan"]
2> lists:sort([L1, L2]).
[[{type1,"Alarm"},{type2,"Started"},{code,"00203"},"Japan"],
 [{type1,"Hello"},{type2,"World"},{code,"00009"},"india",24]]
```

See [8.11  Term Comparisons](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id78713) for more dtails.